# Run selenium tests throught a Proxy service

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

I need to setup a proxy connection in my java selenium-webdriver tests running with maven in Google Chrome browser. I tried several ways as stated in other users questions about proxies, but no one works for my situation.

It gives me no errors, but if i check the Geolocation in "https://www.whatismyip.com/" it shows that the proxy is not used, as I see my real connection IP.

The documentation of the vpn proxy as follows for the curl command in the PHP language:

```
<?php
function getWPage($proxy, $url, $referer, $agent, $header, $timeout) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
$result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
$result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
?>

$proxy = http://<user@vpnservice.com>:<vpn_password>@<country_url>
```

The following example gives me a working browser in where the tests run, but the VPN is not used, as IP is my own and not the one with the VPN, as if it's not using the VPN proxy tunnel.

```
protected String proxyUser = "user@company.com";
protected String proxyPass = "password";
protected String proxyUrl;

public WebDriver initDriverWebPcProxy(String url) throws IOException {
    proxyUrl = "http://" + proxyUser + ":" + proxyPass + "@" + url;

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyUrl);
    proxy.setSslProxy(proxyUrl);
    capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");


    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

    return driver;
}
```

Comment: First of all you call it a VPN but your code seems to signify a proxy. It is two completely different things on different levels in the network stack. Is it a proxy?

Comment: In fact it's a VPN, but as in the example they have in the documentation names they call themselves a proxy, I followed the proxy examples with no success. I didn't found a way to configure vpn's in selenium, only proxy configurations

Comment: in the manual it says... "this is a networking solution and not a software solution. Hence, any platform or software that supports proxy overlaying or proxy connection forwarding is compatible with Direct Connect services."